# SQL - How can I find the average of an SQL statement with a LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, average

Currently I'm working with a database on phpmyadmin. I'm trying to find the Average of an SQL statement that is implementing a LIMIT code.

SQL Statement -

**SELECT avg(value) FROM que LIMIT 10**

The problem with the code is its not averaging the first 10 numbers in value column, but all of them. So the LIMIT 10 isn't actually working. Is there anyway to avoid this or an alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'first 10 numbers'? In RDBMS order of rows is not as it is in seq. files. You should specify a definition of 'first' so that you get meaningful result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT avg(value)
FROM (select value
      from que
      LIMIT 10
     ) q;
```

Do note, however, that use of `limit` without an `order by` produces arbitrary results -- there is no definition of the "first ten" records in a table.